# How to update Firebase token in Flutter application after it expires and store it?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have created authentication with google on first time start up of app and I have my own `_authenticatedUser` which stores user token for further requests.

```
final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<String> signInGoogle() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication gsa = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.signInWithGoogle(
        idToken: gsa.idToken, accessToken: gsa.accessToken);
    var token = await user.getIdToken();
    _authenticatedUser = User(id: user.uid, email: user.email, token: token, photo: user.photoUrl);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('loggedin', 'Google');
    prefs.setString('token', token);
    prefs.setString('userEmail', user.email);
    prefs.setString('userId', user.uid);
    prefs.setString('userImage', user.photoUrl);
    return 'okay';
  }
```

I then call `getCurrentUser()` function in `initState()` to check user is there or not but when the token expires then I get faulty user with expired token.

```
  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    if (user != null) {
      print('signed in');
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String token = prefs.getString('token');
      String uid = prefs.getString('userId');
      String email = prefs.getString('userEmail');
      String photo = prefs.getString('photo');
      _authenticatedUser = User(email: email, id: uid, token: token, photo: photo);
      return user;
    } else {
      print('user is null');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Please someone explain how to fix this?

I redirect user on the basis of return of `getCurrentUser` in main.dart file.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have similar issue.. The plugin only return the idtoken but I need the refresh token when user signing to google..

Comment: @user2570135 did you find the solution? I'm stuck with the same problem. I need the refreshToken, already have the idToken and it's valid !

Answer (score 7):

Today I had the same issue in my app with graphQl. The answer was found in documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

We can see (copy-paste from documentation):

1. Firebase Authentication sessions are long lived.
2. Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last for an hour.

So, there is a lot of different ways to solve this problem. We can check state and revoke token, we can mutate state with Provider or Inherited widgets, we can use BLoC pattern for keeping it fresh.

But, in any case we will have one issue - what if user close app and open it after 2-3 days? Of course user have to be automatically authenticated and he shouldn't notice anything.

My decision was to use update token method, for your case it could look like:

```
  void updateToken() {
    if (firebaseAuth.currentUser() != null) {
      firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((val) {
        val.getIdToken(refresh: true).then((onValue) {
          // here you can mutate state to BLoC or Provider 
          // or Inherited widget
          // for example - authBloc.passFirebaseToken.add(onValue.token);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

That's it. You can place all this auth methods to Singleton and use them on any page where is issue is possible.

Comment: is it good if i put it on my splashscreen? because I got issue 'invalid_refresh_token' when user not open the app for days or weeks.

Comment: Sure, it is a good point to initialise some things.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and fixed it by:

```
Future refreshFirebaseUser() async {
  if (auth.currentUser != null) {
    final user = auth.currentUser;
    final idTokenResult = await user!.getIdTokenResult(true);
    return idTokenResult;
  }
}
```

Just call the function ideally during login/signup

Answer (score 0):

Save the **ID tokens** in local and then use the token as provided in the following code.ID tokens are **short lived** so we are basically refreshing it when expires.

```js
_getToken() async {
  String token = prefs.getString("token") ? ? "";
  String expiryDate = prefs.getString("token_expiry") ? ? "";
  DateTime ? expiryDateTime =
    expiryDate == "" ? null : DateTime.parse(expiryDate);
  if (expiryDateTime != null && DateTime.now().isAfter(expiryDateTime)) {
    //  token expired get new token and save to prefs
    IdTokenResult ? idTokenResult =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser ? .getIdTokenResult();
    String ? fbIdToken = idTokenResult ? .token;
    if (fbIdToken != null) {
      prefs.setString("token", fbIdToken);
      prefs.setString(
        "token_expiry", idTokenResult!.expirationTime.toString());
    }
    token = fbIdToken ? ? "";
  }
  return token;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue and what I did was this:

In my main method, I check if the current user is null, i.e. if there is no user signed in, then I redirect the user to the landing page where they have the chance to login or signup. If the user is not null, then I fetch the user token from the place where it is stored in my database and fetch the current user token, if they are different or if the one stored in the database is null(i.e, there was never one in the first place) the then I update the token with the current one.

In my login, I do the same. After logging in successfully, I check if the token stored for that user is different and if it is, I updated it.

In my signup, I simply get the token for the device and store it with the user's information. I hope this helps. I also know its an old question but I ran into the problem and thought I would share a possible solution for anyone who is looking.

Comment: How do you update the token when it expire .? if the one store in your db is the idtoken and it expire,,Basically. how do you get a refresh token from the idToken

Comment: I do not know if there is any way to "get a refresh token from the idToken". What I do is in the main method, I fetch the current token and compare it with the token I have for it in the database. If it is different, I updated with the most updated one. Are you asking for a way to get the most updated token ?