# Upload FCM Token after signing in

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to apply this in Flutter, thank you.

When the user login uploads the firebase token to the server without duplicating thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this: [How to update Firebase token in Flutter application after it expires and store it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279497/how-to-update-firebase-token-in-flutter-application-after-it-expires-and-store-i)

Comment: Hi thank you for your respond, what I need to achieve is this

1. After login you need to upload Firebase token to the server.
2. You also store Firebase token on local storage. In the case Firebase creates a new token please compare with local. If it is different or not exist, please call api to upload firebase
3. Api to upload FCM

For example:
Method: POST
Request body: 
// 1: iOS, 0: Android,
{
"os": 1,
"token": "FCM Token"
}